# French Characters are not saving in database via php

Tags: php, mysql, collation

I am using the MySQL and PHP to save posts into database. But when i write French language or any other characters in Description. It is not saving it.
But Simple text is Saving perfectly.

This is my Connection file

```
DEFINE('DATABASE_USER', 'db_user');
DEFINE('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'db_password');
DEFINE('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DATABASE_NAME', 'db_name');

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

ini_set('SMTP', "mail.myt.mu"); // Overide The Default Php.ini settings for sending mail


//This is the address that will appear coming from ( Sender )
define('EMAIL', 'k4baber@hotmail.com');

/*Define the root url where the script will be found such as http://website.com or http://website.com/Folder/ */
DEFINE('WEBSITE_URL', 'http://haitibravo.com');


// Make the connection:
$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    DATABASE_NAME);

if (!$dbc) {
    trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

I tried `mysqli_real_escap()` also $desc = `mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']);` But it is not saving at all .
The HTML Form submits all the information to this File..

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"])){

        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $category = $_REQUEST['category'];
        $subcategory = $_REQUEST['items'];
        $desc = $_REQUEST['description'];
        $keywords = $_REQUEST['keywords'];
        $address = "NULL";
        $state = "NULL";
        $city = $_REQUEST['city'];
        $zones = $_REQUEST['zones'];
        $country = $_REQUEST['country'];
        $postcode = "0000";
        $phone = $_REQUEST['u_phone'];


        $image_name1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
        $image_size1 =$_FILES['image1']['size'];
        $image_tmp1 =$_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
        $image_name1='prog'.rand().$image_name1;
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp1,'add_images/'.$image_name1);



        $image_name2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
        $image_size2 =$_FILES['image2']['size'];
        $image_tmp2 =$_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
        $image_name2='prog'.rand().$image_name2;
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp2,'add_images/'.$image_name2);

        $image_name3 = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
        $image_size3 =$_FILES['image3']['size'];
        $image_tmp3 =$_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'];
        $image_name3='prog'.rand().$image_name3;
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp3,'add_images/'.$image_name3);

        $price = $_REQUEST['price'];
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $u_id = $_SESSION['u_id'];
        $u_name= $_SESSION['u_name'];
        $status= "0";
        $flag = "0";
$mysql_query = "INSERT INTO `bravo_ads`(`ad_title`, `ad_category`, `ad_sub_cat`, `ad_description`, `ad_keywords`, `ad_address`, `ad_state`, `ad_city`, `ad_zone`, `ad_country`, `post_code`, `ad_img_1`, `ad_img_2`, `ad_img_3`, `ad_price`, `u_id`, `u_name`, `u_phone`, `ad_date`, `ad_status`, `flag`) VALUES ('$name','$category','$subcategory','$desc','$keywords','$address','$state', '$city', '$zones','$country','$postcode','$image_name1','$image_name2','$image_name3','$price','$u_id','$u_name', '$phone', '$date','$status','$flag')";

        $query_OK = mysqli_query($dbc, $mysql_query);

        if($query_OK){
            $message = '<div class="success"><b>Operation avec success...!</b> Votre produit a bien été posté . Il sera publié après approbation Administrateur</div>';

        }else{

            $message = '<div class="failed"><b>Operation échoué...!</b> Desoler, Votre produit nas pas ete afficher . Quelque chose a mal tourné . Veuillez réessayer plus encore</div>';
        }}
```

`$desc`, `$name`, `$keywords` These things creates issue when i try to save

Comment: Is the page and DB in UTF8? Can you provide the code you are attempting to write with and a string that fails?

Comment: database collation is latin_general_ci

Comment: Collation and character set should be utf8, unless you are converting the non-ascii characters to entities.

Comment: And when i save "Produits &Eacute;lectroniques, Voitures, V&ecirc;tements, Objets de coll&eacute;ction, Bons d'achat et autres achats en ligne" this as description. It fails

Comment: Oh, okay so you are converting it to entities. Can you update the question with your current code? Does it throw a 500 or give any errors?

Comment: But still i am unable to save it

Comment: It just say. Sorry. Operation failed. Means the error which i set to echo if fail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93265/discussion-between-chris85-and-m-baber-zaman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First always check for errors on your query. Do do this use [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

So in your else where you just output `failure` put in:

```
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbc));
```

This will give you a detailed message of what is erring.

As you have stated this gave you

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'achat et autres achats en ligne | Bravo Market |Haiti Bravo|HaitBravo Produits' at line 1

Per your provided data as well

> The Title (L'homme )
>   Keywords (L'homme, d'achat)
>   description (Produits Électroniques, Voitures, Vêtements, Objets de colléction, Bons d'achat et autres achats en ligne )

So the quote in `L'homme` is ending your your encapsulated value and then mysql is presuming `homme` is something it should know.

Since you only escaped the description this didn't help. You need to escape all inputs. A better approach is to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

This error you are encountering also is how SQL injections occur. User data should never be directly inputted into a SQL query.

So to put it all together.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"])){

        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['name']);
        $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['category']);
        $subcategory = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['items']);
        $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['description']);
        $keywords = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['keywords']);
        $address = "NULL";
        $state = "NULL";
        $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['city']);
        $zones = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['zones']);
        $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['country']);
        $postcode = "0000";
        $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['u_phone']);


        $image_name1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
        $image_size1 =$_FILES['image1']['size'];
        $image_tmp1 =$_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
        $image_name1='prog'.rand().$image_name1;
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp1,'add_images/'.$image_name1);



        $image_name2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
        $image_size2 =$_FILES['image2']['size'];
        $image_tmp2 =$_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
        $image_name2='prog'.rand().$image_name2;
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp2,'add_images/'.$image_name2);

        $image_name3 = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
        $image_size3 =$_FILES['image3']['size'];
        $image_tmp3 =$_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'];
        $image_name3='prog'.rand().$image_name3;
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp3,'add_images/'.$image_name3);

        $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['price']);
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $u_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_SESSION['u_id']);
        $u_name= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_SESSION['u_name']);
        $status= "0";
        $flag = "0";
$mysql_query = "INSERT INTO `bravo_ads`(`ad_title`, `ad_category`, `ad_sub_cat`, `ad_description`, `ad_keywords`, `ad_address`, `ad_state`, `ad_city`, `ad_zone`, `ad_country`, `post_code`, `ad_img_1`, `ad_img_2`, `ad_img_3`, `ad_price`, `u_id`, `u_name`, `u_phone`, `ad_date`, `ad_status`, `flag`) VALUES ('$name','$category','$subcategory','$desc','$keywords','$address','$state', '$city', '$zones','$country','$postcode','" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $image_name1) . "','" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $image_name2) . "','" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,  $image_name3) . "','$price','$u_id','$u_name', '$phone', '$date','$status','$flag')";

        $query_OK = mysqli_query($dbc, $mysql_query);

        if($query_OK){
            $message = '<div class="success"><b>Operation avec success...!</b> Votre produit a bien été posté . Il sera publié après approbation Administrateur</div>';

        }else{
            printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbc));
            $message = '<div class="failed"><b>Operation échoué...!</b> Desoler, Votre produit nas pas ete afficher . Quelque chose a mal tourné . Veuillez réessayer plus encore</div>';
        }
}
```

Comment: This Worked Perfectly. Thank you So much @chris85